# User Control accessing wrong directory when connecting to database

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, visual-studio, user-controls

I created a User Control as a container to act as a billing row for an invoicing program, but when I try to add it to a form, it tries to connect to a database at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\DatabaseName.mdf rather than my project directory. Does anyone know how to fix this?

FULL ERROR:

"Failed to create component "InvoiceEntry". The error message follows: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\DatabaseName.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or the specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share."

EDIT: Connection string looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdvVB_Final.My.MySettings.Bauer_BusinessConnectionStringMDF"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Bauer_Business.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

SECOND EDIT: It may also be worth knowing that even if I add it as a databound item in the Designer window, the combobox is not updated with the DB data. If I click Preview Data, the proper data is displayed. It is only during runtime that it does not fill properly.

Comment: What does your connection string look like?

Comment: @zimdanen: Added connection string to original post. I have a feeling that pointing to \DatabaseName.mdf is causing my UserControl to look for the DB in the directory the .dll is located in.

Comment: @zimdanen: Errr, I assume this because the directory where it's looking for the DB is also the default directory for adding a control to the toolbox.

Comment: Have you tried using the AppDomain.SetData method to set the directory, as per [this forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlce/thread/dc31ea59-5718-49b6-9f1f-7039da425296/)?

Comment: I posted my connection string. "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;" (which is weird, since it's not SQLEXPRESS). If I change the DataSource from .\SQLEXPRESS it doesn't connect to the database at all. Plus, my DB connection works correctly everywhere else in the program. I should be looking in app.config, right?

Comment: Couldn't figure it out, but I worked around it. I passed the DataSource to the ComboBox in the code for the form which instantiates it, then used cboName.DataSource to access any information needed from the table within the control code.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same problem. What was happening was that I connected to the database inside my constructor causing the database connection to be called at design time, which wasn't working... To solve this I moved my database interaction to the controls load event.